# Python / Pandas - Selecting columns and rows to apply equation

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
              ano   id             unit period             Sales  ...
business_id                                                        
9564         2012  302                s  anual        5964168.52   
9564         2011  303                k  anual        5774707.15   
2361         2013  304                s  anual        3652575.31
```

For each row, if unit is 'k' I want to multiply the values in the column sales all the next ones by 1000. This one should look like this:

```
              ano   id             unit period             Sales  ...
business_id                                                        
9564         2012  302                s  anual        5964168.52   
9564         2011  303                k  anual     5774707000.15   
2361         2013  304                s  anual        3652575.31
```

--> I want to apply it in column sales and in all the next ones (so that would be the fourth column and on)

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix boolean indexing with `iloc`, but you can easily achieve the same result using `loc` and indexing off of the columns in the dataframe.

For example, to get each column from five onwards in the example above (there is only one) that match your boolean selection:

```
>>> df.loc[df['unit'] == 'k', df.columns[5:]]
        Sales
1  5774707.15
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way, using `.loc` select rows `df.unit == 'k'` and column `Sales`. Use `*=` to multiply these values with `1000`

```
In [1518]: df.loc[df.unit == 'k', 'Sales'] *= 1000

In [1519]: df
Out[1519]:
              ano   id unit period         Sales
business_id
9564         2012  302    s  anual  5.964169e+06
9564         2011  303    k  anual  5.774707e+09
2361         2013  304    s  anual  3.652575e+06
```

If you want it multiple columns.

```
In [1526]: df
Out[1526]:
              ano   id unit period       Sales      Nsales
business_id
9564         2012  302    s  anual  5964168.52  5984168.52
9564         2011  303    k  anual  5774707.15  5794707.15
2361         2013  304    s  anual  3652575.31  3672575.31

In [1527]: df.loc[df.unit == 'k', ['Sales', 'Nsales']] *= 1000

In [1528]: df
Out[1528]:
              ano   id unit period         Sales        Nsales
business_id
9564         2012  302    s  anual  5.964169e+06  5.984169e+06
9564         2011  303    k  anual  5.774707e+09  5.794707e+09
2361         2013  304    s  anual  3.652575e+06  3.672575e+06
```

Comment: Would there be a way to apply it in the fourth column and on (so I don't have to make a line for each column, my dataframe is huge)?

Comment: And, as pointed above, `.iloc` from positional calls. I usually prefer explicit `.loc` for column names.

Comment: Both suggestions are great, thanks guys. I tried to make @Alexander 's suggestion work but I've go this error: NotImplementedError: iLocation based boolean indexing on an integer type is not available. Any idea on what could that be?

Comment: @abutremutante You should ask the person whose solution you accepted, not anyone else.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ and I did. Alexander had a comment in this thread prior to writing an answer